# Incorrect syntax near the keyword "INTO"

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-insert

This is the `insert` query which is causing error :

```
 public int Insert(User obj){

     string query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO tblUser(Name,Photo,Email,Password,Branch,Phone,Address,Authority,Recover_Email,Facebook_ID)  values(@name,@photo,@email,@pass,@branch,@phone,@addr,@auth,@re,@fbID) ";
     List<SqlParameter> lstp = new List<SqlParameter>();
     lstp.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", obj.Name));
     lstp.Add(new SqlParameter("@photo", obj.Photo));
     lstp.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", obj.Email));
     lstp.Add(new SqlParameter("@pass", obj.Password));
     lstp.Add(new SqlParameter("@branch", obj.Branch));
     lstp.Add(new SqlParameter("@phone", obj.Phone));
     lstp.Add(new SqlParameter("@addr", obj.Address));
     lstp.Add(new SqlParameter("@auth", obj.Authority));
     lstp.Add(new SqlParameter("@re", obj.Recovery_Email));
     lstp.Add(new SqlParameter("@fbID", obj.Facebook_ID));
     return DBUtility.ModifyData(query, lstp);
}
```

**Exception Details :**

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'INTO'

**Table Definition :**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblUser] (
    [UserID]         INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]           VARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [Photo]          VARCHAR (500) NULL,
    [Email]          VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Password]       VARCHAR (500) NULL,
    [Branch]         VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Phone]          VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Address]        VARCHAR (500) NULL,
    [Recovery_Email] VARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [Facebook_ID]    VARCHAR (200) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC)
);
```

If at all needed, **The Stack Trace :**

```
 [SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1787814
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5341674
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +546
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1693
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +275
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +1421
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +208
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +163
   DataAccess.DBUtility.ModifyData(String query, List`1 lstParams) in c:\Users\ABHISHEK\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\InventoryManagement\DataAccess\DBUtility.cs:36
   BusinessLogic.UserLogic.Insert(User obj) in c:\Users\ABHISHEK\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\InventoryManagement\BusinessLogic\UserLogic.cs:30
   InventoryManagementSys.FacebookSync.AuthorizeUser() in c:\Users\ABHISHEK\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\InventoryManagement\InventoryManagementSys\FacebookSync.aspx.cs:83
   InventoryManagementSys.FacebookSync.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\ABHISHEK\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\InventoryManagement\InventoryManagementSys\FacebookSync.aspx.cs:20
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

Comment: why are you using `ignore` here ?

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` is `mysql` syntax.

Comment: @nadeem :  i dont want to allow duplicate entries into my table

Comment: Removed `Sql-Server` tag: this is MySQL specific.

Comment: @Ullas : I have used a similar query in my other asp.net webapp and it works perfectly fine there

Comment: What happens if you run the statement in SQL Workbench (use `declare` to define local variables for the parameters)?

Comment: @Richard : it raises the same error. `Incorrect syntax near "into"`

Comment: I think you are confused: 1. the stack trace shows you are using SQL Server (eg. type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`), but 2. it also fails in MySQL's SQL Workbench. Either you have two errors (MYSQL's SQL syntax and using the wrong database) or perhaps you are confusing SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) the interactive IDE for SQL server with MySQL's SQL Workbench (its IDE).

Comment: I am not using SSMS ! I have added the DB in the visual studio itself by creating "a new Db(.mdf) file! @Richard

Comment: In which case why didn't you say you were *not* using SQL Workbench?

Comment: @Richard : I misunderstood! I am sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you can not use `INSERT IGNORE` into `SQL SERVER`. If you are on `SQL SERVER 2008 onwards` you can use `MERGE` to do an `INSERT` if row does not exist, or an `UPDATE`. e.g.

```
MERGE
INTO    tmp_final dv
USING   tmp_holding_DataValue t
ON      t.dateStamp = dv.dateStamp
        AND t.itemId = dv.itemId
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT  (dateStamp, itemId, value)
VALUES  (dateStamp, itemId, value)
```

Edit: It is clear that you are executing against SQL Server because SQL Server client specific types and methods appear in your stack trace.

Comment: I have used a similar query for my other asp.net project and it works perfectly fine

Comment: This appears to be a MySql specific question: thus I've removed the SQL Server tag (I suspect the asker assumed Sql-Server was a generic tag).

Comment: @Richard I actually suspect they're trying to use code they've seen in mySql within SQL Server - so, the SQL Server tag may be correct.

Comment: @AdrianWragg You may be right: looking at the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments to the question and answers:

You have got [Microsoft's SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server/) RDBMS mixed up with [Oracle's MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) RDBMS.

You need to use T-SQL (Microsoft's SQL dialect) when using SQL Server.

You need to use MySQL's SQL dialect when using MySQL.

While common code to use both can be written, it is significantly more complicated (eg. you need to use the common types (like `DbCommand`) for most code generating the right concrete types with some form of factory layer).

Either use one RDBMS consistently (the easier option) or build the infrastructure (including restricting yourself to the common parts of the SQL dialects) to work across RDBMSs.

Comment: Exactly when I write the test query in the Visual Studio IDE.. Its written as T-SQL... But still my question remains unanswered .. Why the error persists!\

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh Because `INSERT IGNORE INTO…` is not valid T-SQL. The `IGNORE` option is a MySql specific extension.

Comment: But I have used this in my previous ASP .NET projects in the Visual Studio (2010) IDE ... But here now i am using Vs2013 and this error is occuring! Is it because of the versions ?

Comment: You previous project was clearly using MySQL and not SQL Server.

Comment: Okkay then how should I go about writing this query where same records are not interested in VS2013 IDE?